# Big O Notations

Tags: java, big-o, factorial

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Big O Notations Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953244/big-o-notations-questions)

Hi, I need an example in codes with reference to O(N!) time complexity.