# BIG O Analysis of Loops

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

Can someone provide examples of loops that are PolynomialO O(n^2)  , Exponential O(2^n) , and Factorial O(n1). I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

I understand the concepts of 
O(log n)`for (int i=0; i<=10; i=i*2) OR for (int i=0; i<=10; i=i/2)`
O(n)`for (int i=0; i<=10; i++)`or `(int i=10; i<=0; i--)`.
 O(n^2) 
`

```html
for (int i=0; i<=10; i++)
{
    for (int i=0; i<=10; i++)
    {
      //DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably meant `i = i*2` instead of `i*2` (which creates an endless loop...) and as for `i/2` I have no idea what you intended to do there. Further, your question is not clear since there is no `n` in the loops you provide in the examples.

Answer (score 1):

O(n^2):

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
    count++;
  }
}
```

This is pretty simple, for every nested loop you will increase your power. So if you had 3 for loops instead of two, then it would be `O(n^3)`

O(2^n):

```
public int fibonacci(int n){
    if (n<= 1) return n;
    return fibonacci(n- 2) + fibonacci(n- 1);
}
```

For every iteration of this method, two other "branches" will be created (until n<=1) since it has two recursive calls. So the growth doubles for every iteration.

O(n!):

```
public int factorialRuntime(int n) {
  int count = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    count += factorialRuntime(n-1);
  }
  return count;
}
```

This example was pulled from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953244/example-of-on).

Answer (score 1):

A more obviously `O(2^N)` example is:

```
public int count2PowerN(int n) {
  if (n <= 1) {
     return n;
  } else {
     return count2PowerN(n - 1) +  count2PowerN(n - 1);
  }
}
```

Notes:

1. `O(2^N)` is equivalent to any `O(c^N)` where `c` is a constant.  It is conventional to use `e` as the nominal constant; i,e `O(e^N)`
2. you cannot get super-polynomial complexity with simple nested loops.  You need either recursion or a dynamic data structure.